# How can I list all deployed jax-ws webservices?

Tags: java, jax-ws, servlets

I have deployed some jax-ws webservices in a tomcat:
web.xml:

```
...
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>WebServiceJaxWs</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>...a bean of mine which overwrites WSServletDelegate</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
...
```

The webservices themselves are defined in the sun-jaxws.xml

They work just fine.

I now need to write a jsp, which displays all deployed webservices. I have access to the servlet context, but I simple cannot find a way to access the WebServiceJaxWs Servlet. My idea was to access it and then enumerate the published endpoints.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual way I can think of is to parse your `sun-jaxws.xml` and get the information from there.

Comment: Instead of parsing the xml file, which I would only use as a last result, i think i will create a spring bean which holds the urls of the different webservices. The webservices themselves will (on creation) load the bean and add their name. At the end I should have a bean with all urls. The idea is also somewhat dirty, but i see no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could deploy all those web services as JMX beans and see them using JConsole.

Comment: The idea is interesting, but sadly i can not implement it. The Application which includes the webservices is rather big. I can not implement the webservices differently, because I am approaching a deadline and i will not take the risk implementing some new bugs.